# How to select last row of grouped cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, select, grouping

I have a big spreadsheet in Excel. Several rows are grouped and every group has a various number of lines depending on which group it is. I.e

```
Group 1
   1
   2
   3
Group 2
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
```

How do I condition cells to import the value of:

1. the last cell of groups (3 from group 1, 6 from group 2 etc)
2. the middle cell of a group (i.e for group 2, that would mean cell 3)

Comment: Nothing. Don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

for last cell of a column it's:

=INDEX(I:I,MATCH(BIGNUM,I:I))

Now I guess if you can replace I:I with a custom array that might help.

Also, if you have an even number of cells in a group you might have an issue. Sorry I couldn't help more.